# Can we create an xpath for multiple visible & dynamic elements in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I want to create an XPath for visible elements. I tried these two techniques.

```
1. By locator = By.xpath("//a[contains(@style, 'display: none')]")
// It gives the elements those are hidden by display: none property.

2. driver.findElement(locatorXPath).isDisplayed();
// It can throw exceptions like StaleElementException as locatorXPath is the locator for dynamic content i.e. loading icon.`
```

Is there any way we can create an XPath locator to get specific visible elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant create XPath for visible/invisible elements. The first your attempt would return you the element if it has the corresponding attribute. However this rarely happens. In the most cases the styles are assigned through CSS sheets.

XPath is about DOM structure, not about styling.